# MySQL Connection to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following problem:

I cannot open a database connection. Can someone tell me how my database-config has to be if I have this MySQL command?

```
$dh = new DB('table');
$dh->Query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carname LIKE '%{$term}%'");
```

I've already tried something like this:

```
$dh = new DB("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

but it does not work.

So how and where do I have to put in my host, dbpass and dbuser then?

here is my complete code:

```
if(empty($_REQUEST['term']))
        exit;

$term = $_REQUEST['term'];

$dh = new DB('table');
$dh->Query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carname LIKE '%{$term}%'");

$result = array();
$result['results'] = array();
$result['count'] = 0;
while($carname = $dh->FetchArray()){
        $result['count']++;
        $result['results'][] = $carname;
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

i want to get the result back to json.

but the console says:

```
GET http://192.168.50.200:8888/XX/XX/source.php?term=XX 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

is that because i'm not connected to the database?

Comment: What language is this? PHP?

Comment: LIKE '$term$' ? Echo query if stuck, and note that '%...' is always inefficient because it cannot use an index. '...%' can use an index however.

Comment: You're making us guess: 1) The programming language 2) The database library 2) The problem you have

Comment: it's taged as php however what error do you get, what do you exepect as a result?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that his database is actually a 'table' !?whaaaaat?!

Comment: i updated my issue on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your language is php, directly use the following:

```
$connection=mysql_connect("hostname","username","password"); // Try using localhost for hostname

$db=mysql_select_db("db_name");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carname LIKE '%{$term}%'");
```

Comment: he's using some sort of framework I would not recomend him to use pure mysql queries like that

Comment: may be he doesn't know even to make connection with basic mysql queries, that's why I suggested him that

Comment: in that case I would tell him about PDO instead of the out dated mysql_query

Comment: i've allready tried PDO
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

but it doenst work too

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PHP and PDO this is how you should create a connection

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carname LIKE '%:term%'");
$sth->bindParam(':term', $term));
$sth->execute();
```

Also make sure you have enabled PDO in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using core PHP then you can establish connection with database using below code-

```
<?php

mysql_connect("host_name","username","password") or die("server not connected");
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die("database not connected2");

?>
```

and if you are working in wordpress then use following code-

```
<?php
require_once('/path/to/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carname LIKE '%'".$term."'%'");
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and it should not be used any more

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated in PHP 5.5.* Maybe he's using 5.4.*

Comment: mysql_*'s intended replacement, mysqli_*, has been around since php 5.0 which was released in 2004.